# Pauli exclusion during an NMR or EPR pulse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, spin-statistics

If we perform a $\pi/2$-pulse on a pair of spins initally in the singlet state $|S\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle-|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\big)$, in theory we arrive in the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|S\rangle + |T_0\rangle\big) = |\uparrow\downarrow\rangle$ - as best I can tell this had been realised experimentally, e.g in Figure 4A of https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1116955.
However, if the two-electron spin wavefunction is $|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle$, then no spatial wavefunction can result in a **total** wavefunction that is antisymmetric under permuting the two electrons.

My question is: how is this compatible with the Pauli exclusion principle, or rather the more general principle that fermion wavefunctions need to be antisymmetric? I understand that in these systems $|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle$ is neither an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, nor of the spin operator $S^2$, so perhaps only spin/energy eigenstates need to be antisymmetric?

I realise that any question involving field-induced spin dynamics is probably best understood in the formalism of QFT, which I'm not very familiar with - please feel free to direct me to any reading on this sort of thing!

Comment: A rotation of the singlet state leaves this state invariant, *i.e.* it does not produce $\vert \uparrow\downarrow\rangle$.  *By definition* the singlet state remains unchanged under rotation.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero thanks for your comment! I'm a bit confused about the invariance under rotation - do you mean a rotation of the spins in space? I meant a $\pi/2$ rotation around the $|S\rangle$-$|T_0\rangle$ Bloch sphere as in NMR literature, which is carried out using magnetic field pulses. My fault for not being specific.

Comment: I mean rotation of the spin in space.  A singlet state has $J=0$ (and so $M=0$) so denoting this by $\vert 00\rangle$, any rotation $R_k(\alpha)$ by any angle $\alpha$ about any axis $k$ will leave $\vert 00\rangle$ unchanged, else it would not be a singlet.  That's also baked in the name: singlet means there is a single state in the list of possible states to be reached by rotation, so this state has "nowhere to go" under rotation.